# JavaScript runtime error: Control ClientID is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a .ascx ComboBoxControl defined as below. Lets call it **Control1**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="ComboBoxControl" Codebehind="ComboBoxControl.ascx.cs" %>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0px solid red">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 60px; vertical-align: top">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelectedMLValues" class="dropdownbox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Style="width: 60px;" EnableViewState="true" Font-Size="11px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:14px;" class="imgalign" align="left">
            <img alt="" id="imgShowHide" runat="server" src="~/Images/drop.gif" height="20" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DropDownLook"  style="vertical-align: top" colspan="2">
            <div style="vertical-align: top;">
                <div id="divCheckBoxListClose" runat="server" class="DivClose" style="font-weight:700;color:Black; font-size:11;padding-left:6px;">
                    <label id="lblClose" runat="server" class="LabelClose Green" >
                        Click Here To Close <span class="closecross" style="vertical-align:text-bottom; margin-bottom:-1px; " >X</span></label>
                </div>
                <div id="divCheckBoxList" runat="server" class="DivCheckBoxList">                    
                <div>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" CssClass="CheckBoxList leftPaddingforcombo" Text="ALL" ToolTip="ALL"/>
                    </div>
                   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkMultipleValues"  runat="server" CssClass="CheckBoxList" 
                        Width="500px"  >
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the controls code behind .cs file, i have below code that sets the ComboBoxControl's onClick event.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtSelectedMLValues.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowMList(" + divCheckBoxList.ClientID + "," + divCheckBoxListClose.ClientID + ")");
            chkMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onblur", "HideMList(" + divCheckBoxList.ClientID + "," + divCheckBoxListClose.ClientID + ")");
            chkMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onclick", "FindSelectedItems(this," + txtSelectedMLValues.ClientID + "," + chkAll.ClientID + ");");         
        }
}
```

I'm using the above ComboBoxControl (**Control1**) in another .ascx control (Lets call it **Control2**) like below.

```
<td width="15px" style="text-align: left;display: inline-block;">
 <uc2:ComboBoxControl ID="ComboBoxControlNames" runat="server" />
</td>
```

The problem i'm having is that when i select a checkbox in the ComboBoxControl, i get the following error "***ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ComboBoxControlNames_txtSelectedMLValues' is undefined***"

Note that "ContentPlaceHolderMain" is an asp:ContentPlaceHolder in my MasterPage.

When i view the page source, ClientID "**ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ComboBoxControlNames_txtSelectedMLValues**"  is there but IE 11 is throwing an error that it is undefined.

In chrome, the error doesn't appear. I'm struggling with how to stop that error in IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will render as

```
<input onclick="ShowMList( theOneId, theOtherId)" />
```

As you can see they will be seen as variables and not strings. You need to wrap them in quotes.

```
txtSelectedMLValues.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowMList('" + divCheckBoxList.ClientID + "','" + divCheckBoxListClose.ClientID + "')");
```

now do that for the others